# Different rendering but same weight for different items in the recyclerview

Tags: android, android-layout, listview, android-recyclerview

I have a recyclerview with items having weights. Every item is being displayed differently (the width) even though the weight is same. I want equal widths for all the textviews in each item.

[image: The rendered image]

Comment: Instead of using weight you can define the width in dp's and tell your ViewHolder layout to have exact width for each item. There is no need for you to use weights here.

Answer (score 0):

I figured out the mistake. I forgot to make layout_width 0dp. Thanks